# Android: Unbuffered IO

Tags: java, android

I want to use an Non Blocking IO to read a stream/output from a background process.Can anyone give me an example on how to use the Non Blocking IO on Android?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your post. Are you talking about non-buffered I/O or non-blocking I/O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [the class I use](http://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery/blob/master/src/info/lamatricexiste/network/Network/DownloadFile.java#L50) to download a file from the internet or copy a file within the filesystem and how I use it:

```
// Download a file to /data/data/your.app/files
new DownloadFile(ctxt, "http://yourfile", ctxt.openFileOutput("destinationfile.ext", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

// Copy a file from raw resource to the files directory as above
InputStream in = ctxt.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);
OutputStream out = ctxt.openFileOutput("filename.ext", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final ReadableByteChannel ic = Channels.newChannel(in);
final WritableByteChannel oc = Channels.newChannel(out);
DownloadFile.fastChannelCopy(ic, oc);
```

There also is the Selector approach, here are some great (Java) tutorials about Selectors, Channels and Threads:

1. http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/05/30/tricks-and-tips-with-nio-part-i-why-you-must-handle-op_write
2. http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/07/06/tricks-and-tips-with-nio-part-ii-why-selectionkey-attach-is-evil/
3. http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/07/07/tricks-and-tips-with-nio-part-iii-to-thread-or-not-to-thread/
4. http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/07/19/httpweblogs-java-netblog20060719tricks-and-tips-nio-part-iv-meet-selectors/
5. http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/09/21/tricks-and-tips-with-nio-part-v-ssl-and-nio-friend-or-foe/

Comment: `WritableByteChannel.write()` is still blocking in my case.

Comment: This is not a non-blocking implementation.

Answer (score 1):

background operation can be done in many ways in Android. I suggest you to use AsyncTask:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  // perform long running operation operation
  return null;
 }

 /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
  */
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
 }

 /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
  */
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
 // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For example showing ProgessDialog
 }

 /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
  */
 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
  }
}
```

Then you execute it like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   new LongOperation().execute("");
}
```

reference: [xoriant.com](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html)

In the doInBackground method, you can put your file access stuff. 
reference for file access can be found in the android developer site.